# Setting up iso repository

Tags: linux, debian

I have an iso image of debian repository `/root/rep/dvd-1.iso.`
Also I have a folder `/mnt/dvd-1`
I added a string to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file

```
deb file:///mnt/dvd-1/ wheesy contrib main non-free
```

I mounted my image to the mount point with

```
mount -t iso9660 /root/rep/dvd-1.iso /mnt/dvd-1 -o loop
```

And got message that it mounted only for read. It's ok, I want only to read.

But when I enter command

```
aptitude update
```

I'm getting several error messages like

```
Failed to fetch file:/mnt/dvd-1/dists/wheesy/contrib/binary-i386/Packages: File not found
```

But this file (as well as others) really exists (I checked). Because of this error I can't install packages from iso's. Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: `wheesy`? you probably mean `wheezy`!

Comment: Oh, great, thanks, that was my mistake. Write again please below, I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wheesy` should probably be `wheezy`, there is no debian distro with that the former name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with **apt-cdrom**?